# need to add a progress bar for when a (blocking) DLL call is busy

Tags: delphi

my delphi 2009 app uses a DLL that performs some activities that may take several seconds.  i'd like to show a progress bar.  unfortunately the DLL call is a blocking call & has no callback function.

a way i've been  considering is to add a TTimer to my app.  when the timer event fires, i look at the time and use that to calculate the progress % and update the progress bar.

i did that, would i have problems with the fact that the VCL is not thread safe?

thank you!

Comment: What is your question exactly? I can't tell from the accepted answer... Is it "If I did that, would I ..." or is it "I did that, will I ...". In any case, without either calling the DLL from a secondary thread or cooperation from the DLL it can't be done, so I'm at a loss why you accepted the answer already. What's the question, and what's the answer to it, and why? Very puzzling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about Delphi but if it runs on windows , you might need to do this.

1) Because your user interface is not thread safe, you need to PostMessage into the user-interface thread to update the progress bar.

2) If your user-interface thread is the thread calling into the DLL, then you wont be pumping messages, so you cant update your user-interface. You could call MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx to continue pumping messages while waiting, but since the wait is within the DLL , you dont have a handle to wait for. Is it possible to move your call into the DLL to another thread ? Then you can wait on that thread handle. This way your progress bar will continue to operate.

I dont know much about Delphi, but my colleagues tell me it runs Win32 based function calls, so it operates very much like a windows program on windows.

Comment: More than "very much like" a windows program on Windows - it IS a native Win32 windows program (same as if it had been written in VS C++).

Answer (score 1):

Since the DLL is blocking, you need to call it from a secondary worker thread.  If you call it in the main thread, your TTimer will be blocked and thus unable to update the UI.